Going beyond the letter of the law: the comment of the Shita Mekubetzes
The Shita Mekubetzes on Bava Metzia 24b writes:

למי שאינו כל כך אדם חשוב דלא מחייבינן ליה לעשות לפנים משורת הדין
This
applies to someone who is not such an important person, for whom we do
not obligate to go beyond the letter of the law.

The Shita Mekubetzes, citing Rabbeinu Yehonsan, explains that a person of distinction, by virtue of his stature, is halachically obligated to go beyond the letter of the law (לפנים משורת הדין) (ArtScroll-translation).
However, aren't we meant to go beyond the letter of the law, even when we are benonim and not tzadikkim per se (as per the Bartenura) here.
What exactly does this Shita Mekubetzes mean? And how to reconcile it with the explanation of Avos and the Bartenura there? Isn't it the best way to act לפנים משורת הדין?

Related: When must we go beyond the Torah? and How come Rav Nachman isn’t happy with someone going beyond the letter of the law?.

@RabbiKaii I edited it :)

It seems that what he is saying here is that we - Beis Din - don’t obligate him in such a case.

@Sholom but then the question remains why. It is a good thing to return a object and to act beyond the letter of the law.

Nevertheless we can’t always make you do something, just because it is a good thing to do.

@Sholom Agreed. But I don't think that is what this is about. The Shita Mekubetzes says that we cannot force a non-important person to לפנים משורת הדין. My question is why?

Because if we can force you, then it is no longer לפנים משורת הדין - BEYOND the letter of the law.

But, if you force a non-important person, there is also no לפנים משורת הדין. It seems to me that לפנים משורת הדין is not only applicable to tzaddikim, right? So, why would this commentary say that it refers to a "אדם חשוב"?

Your proof as per the Bartenura is the answer: that is called being a Chosid - not a regular Benoni. So what is your question again? That we are expected to all become VIPs? sure we are, working on it...
